# Ubuntu Server Can't Detect Whole Disk

Tags: server, partitioning, gparted, disk-usage, 21.04

There is something wrong with my system and I couldn't identify the problem since many days. I have 256Gb disk but my system can recognize only approximately half of it. I have created a live Ubuntu Desktop and run Gparted, it shows ext4 as 220G instead of 109G as it should be.

Here are some SS:

[image: lsblk -f]

[image: df -Th]

Thanks for any contributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally find the answer. You should change +100G part with your missing space. This was a problem about my logical volume size.

[image]

I didn't hit enter again on last line as I did it already but you should. You will see a message about resizing was succesful. Nothing else to do afterwards. Just that.